# How to get elements from a cloned div

Tags: javascript

I have a div I have cloned that has elements inside it. I want to get the heading (h2) value out of the second child in the div

How do I go about this? I want to get the "bent over row" value from `<div class="heading_add"><h2>Bent over row</h2>`

```js
 // Make heading and button 
    let headingDiv = document.createElement('div');
    headingDiv.classList = "heading_add"
    let newh2 = document.createElement('h2');
    newh2.innerHTML = itemRef.name;
    headingDiv.appendChild(newh2)
    videoCard.appendChild(headingDiv)
 
 // Clones the div with video 
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      const exercises = document.querySelector('.exercises');
      let clone = videoCard.cloneNode(true); //Clones the div tags I'm trying to get
      clone.defaultMuted = true;
      let firstKid = clone.firstChild;
      let secondChild = firstKid.firstChild.muted = true;
      let meTest = firstKid.firstChild;
      clone.classList.add('newVid');
      console.log(meTest)
      exercises.appendChild(clone)
    });
```

```html
<div class="videoCard newVid">
  <div class="vid"> 
    <video src="videostoredinfirebase" width="300" class="videoAdded" autoplay="" loop=""></video>
  </div>
  <div class="heading_add"><h2>Bent over row</h2>
  <button class="add_video_btn">+</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `let firstKid = clone.firstChild;` as far as I understand, this would be `<div class="vid">`, and this `let meTest = firstKid.firstChild;` would be `<video src="videostoredinfirebase" ...`

Comment: I think you need the second child, not the first. Something like: `let headingDiv = clone.childNodes[1]; let h2text = headingDiv.firstChild.textContent;`

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix

```js
function add() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(divClone);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      <h2>
        This is a div
      </h2>
    </div>
    <button onclick="add()">+</button>
  </body>
</html>
```